# Nested for loop for n number

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a piece of code for which I need to define a function such that it will work for any number ***n***.

```
Dic1 = {'a':0.001,'b':0.999,'c':0.0}
Dic2 = {'a':0.018,'b':0.982,'c':0.0}
Dic3 = {'a':0.999,'b':0.001,'c':0.0}
Dic4 = {'a':0.999,'b':0.001,'c':0.0}
sets=set(Dic1.keys()).union(set(Dic2.keys())).union(set(Dic3.keys())).union(set(Dic4.keys()))
print(sets)
Result=dict.fromkeys(sets,0)
## Combination process
for i in Dic1.keys():
    for j in Dic2.keys():
      for k in Dic3.keys():
        for l in Dic4.keys():
          if set(str(i)).intersection(set(str(j))).intersection(set(str(k))).intersection(set(str(l))) == set(str(i)):
              Result[i]+=Dic1[i]*Dic2[j]*Dic3[k]*Dic4[l]
          elif set(str(i)).intersection(set(str(j))).intersection(set(str(k))).intersection(set(str(l))) == set(str(j)):
              Result[j]+=Dic1[i]*Dic2[j]*Dic3[k]*Dic4[l]
          elif set(str(i)).intersection(set(str(j))).intersection(set(str(k))).intersection(set(str(l))) == set(str(k)):
              Result[k]+=Dic1[i]*Dic2[j]*Dic3[k]*Dic4[l]
          elif set(str(i)).intersection(set(str(j))).intersection(set(str(k))).intersection(set(str(l))) == set(str(l)):
              Result[l]+=Dic1[i]*Dic2[j]*Dic3[k]*Dic4[l]
f= sum(list(Result.values()))
print(f)
for i in Result.keys():
  Result[i] /=f
print(Result)
```

So if I have only 3 dictionaries then the code should be

```
Dic1 = {'a':0.001,'b':0.999,'c':0.0}
Dic2 = {'a':0.018,'b':0.982,'c':0.0}
Dic3 = {'a':0.999,'b':0.001,'c':0.0}
sets=set(Dic1.keys()).union(set(Dic2.keys())).union(set(Dic3.keys()))
print(sets)
Result=dict.fromkeys(sets,0)
## Combination process
for i in Dic1.keys():
    for j in Dic2.keys():
      for k in Dic3.keys():
          if set(str(i)).intersection(set(str(j))).intersection(set(str(k))) == set(str(i)):
              Result[i]+=Dic1[i]*Dic2[j]*Dic3[k]
          elif set(str(i)).intersection(set(str(j))).intersection(set(str(k))) == set(str(j)):
              Result[j]+=Dic1[i]*Dic2[j]*Dic3[k]
          elif set(str(i)).intersection(set(str(j))).intersection(set(str(k))) == set(str(k)):
              Result[k]+=Dic1[i]*Dic2[j]*Dic3[k]
f= sum(list(Result.values()))
print(f)
for i in Result.keys():
  Result[i] /=f
print(Result)
```

In short for ***n*** dictionaries, the variable ***sets*** should also change along with the combination process. How do I proceed with this?

Comment: [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are doing whole lot of looping to simply multiply values from similar keys together.  Here is an example of how you could do this in pandas, but there are examples on SO where you can multiple multiple dicts together w/o using other libraries.

In any case, you just need a list of your dicts before proceeding, in this case `d`

```
import pandas as pd

Dic1 = {'a':0.001,'b':0.999,'c':0.0}
Dic2 = {'a':0.018,'b':0.982,'c':0.0}
Dic3 = {'a':0.999,'b':0.001,'c':0.0}
Dic4 = {'a':0.999,'b':0.001,'c':0.0}

d = [Dic1,Dic2,Dic3,Dic4]

df = pd.DataFrame(d).prod()
df.div(sum(df.values)).to_dict()
```

Output

```
{'a': 0.9482176755958659, 'b': 0.05178232440413414, 'c': 0.0}
```

Comment: This solution works properly and is very clean. Upvoting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list containing all dictionaries:

```
lst_tot = [Dic1, Dic2, Dic3, Dic4]
```

First for the variable `sets` you can do:

```
sets = set(val for dic in lst_tot for val in dic.keys())
```

Then for your for-loops, I found out that you want to multiply the values of the key when the key is present in all dictionaries. You only need to loop over all possible keys, these are computed in `sets`. To verify if the key is available in all dictionaries you can do:

```
all([key in dic for dic in lst_tot])
```

Now to multiply all values use `math.prod(list)` and you get in total:

```
import math

Dic1 = {'a':0.001,'b':0.999,'c':0.0}
Dic2 = {'a':0.018,'b':0.982,'c':0.0}
Dic3 = {'a':0.999,'b':0.001,'c':0.0}
Dic4 = {'a':0.999,'b':0.001,'c':0.0}

lst_tot = [Dic1, Dic2, Dic3, Dic4]

sets = set(val for dic in lst_tot for val in dic.keys())
print(sets)
Result = dict.fromkeys(sets, 0)

## Combination process
for key in sets:
    if all([key in dic for dic in lst_tot]):
        Result[key] += math.prod([dic[key] for dic in lst_tot])

f = sum(list(Result.values()))
print(f)
for i in Result.keys():
  Result[i] /= f
print(Result)
```

Comment: The solution works only for Python version >=3.8. However, for other versions, we need to change the code a bit.